# POST request from Nuxt to Laravel Sanctum ends up at login page

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js, usefetch

I spend hours trying to debug googling arround but with no good result.
I am using Laravel 8 with Sanctum package and latest Nuxt as frond-end. I setup couple endpoints and made them work - GET requests only. When I got to the forms section, where I need to retrieve information about form and then to be able to send this form data back to Laravel via POST request, I am not able within my set of middleware.

If I am using Api route, I end up at admin login page because of the
`\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class`
and if I use Web route, I end up at same login page because of the
'\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,'
if in both cases I comment them, my POST request goes through. To be exact, both work with Postman and I get no redirect. I get this behaviour only from Nuxt fetch.

This is example of my Nuxt code:

```
async function sendForm(){
    if(form.value.email_honeypot == ''){
        form.value.email_honeypot = props.data.honey;

        await useFetch('/sanctum/csrf-cookie', { credentials: 'include' });
        const token = useCookie('XSRF-TOKEN')
        form.value._token = token.value;

        formData.value.errors = {};
        const { data: responseData, error, status } = await useCustomFetch('/api/forms-plugin/1/submit', { method: "POST", watch: false, body: form.value, headers: { Accept: 'application/json', 'X-XSRF-TOKEN': token.value }})
        formData.value.response = responseData;

        if(responseData.value.errors) {
            for (const key in responseData.value.errors) {
                const parts = key.split('.');
                const fieldId = parseInt(parts[1]);
                formData.value.errors[fieldId] = responseData.value.errors[key][0];
            }
        }

        if(responseData.value.message) {
            formData.value.success = true;
        }

        form.value.email_honeypot = '';
    }
}
```

Fetching XSRF-TOKEN from sanctum works okay, I get those cookies to my Application cookie right.
Could anyone help me with this?

Usually when post requests failed as I mentioned, my terminal gives me only this:
`Closed without sending a request; it was probably just an unused speculative preconnection`

cors.php

```
    'paths' => ['*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => [env('FRONTEND_URL', 'http://localhost:3000')],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

.env

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:3000

SESSION_DOMAIN=.localhost
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false

SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=127.0.0.1:8000,localhost:3000,localhost
```

nuxt.config.ts

```
  routeRules: {
    '/api/**': {
      proxy: { to: "http://localhost:8000/api/**" },
    },

    '/sanctum/**': {
      proxy: { to: "http://localhost:8000/sanctum/**" },
    }
  }
```

useCustomFetch.ts

```
import type { UseFetchOptions } from 'nuxt/app'
import { defu } from 'defu'

export function useCustomFetch<T> (url: string, options: UseFetchOptions<T> = {}) {
    const config = useRuntimeConfig()

    const defaults: UseFetchOptions<T> = {
        baseURL: config.public.baseUrl,
        // cache request - causes trouble with url
        // key: url,

        // set user token if connected
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${config.public.accessToken}`,
            Accept: 'application/json',
        },

        credentials: 'include',

        onResponse (_ctx) {
            // _ctx.response._data = new myBusinessResponse(_ctx.response._data)
        },

        onResponseError (_ctx) {
            // throw new myBusinessError()
        }
    }

    // for nice deep defaults, please use unjs/defu
    const params = defu(options, defaults)

    return useFetch(url, params)
}
```

I tried commenting those two middlewares and it starts to work. So I guess I need to make it work with Sanctum EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class. But I do not know how.

Comment: Have you carefully compared your requests (url, method, headers, cookies) between Postman and your browser ?

Comment: I tried many times to match those, but even than with no better result. Right now I notices sometimes I get body sent as params to url.

Comment: Can you share your useCustomFetch() function ?

Comment: When you debug your params, just before useFetch, in your useCustomFetch, is everything ok ?

Comment: With parameters I believe so. I get this request reported by nuxt
{
  "baseURL": "http://localhost:3000",
  "headers": {
    "Authorization": "Bearer 1|XDMKyEfHYxxvoS9PnUYnW7Myr06vVdzrf3ES1ujK",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "X-XSRF-TOKEN": "r5aQ0WppJggheoqBVyFGCzd0unOzL3PatTfnx9Uk",
    "X-CSRF-TOKEN": "r5aQ0WppJggheoqBVyFGCzd0unOzL3PatTfnx9Uk"
  },
  "credentials": "include",
  "method": "POST",
  "watch": false,
  "body": {}
}

where body is empty because I have not filled any input
and this usefetch works with authorization token as get request goes through sanctum

Comment: if I comment \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class this post request works

Comment: I just found out it strictly csrf problem and it looks like session token does not match token in cookie and it looks like some is encrypted and other is not.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I solved the issue.

#1 do not put multiple tokens in request, use only X-XSRF-TOKEN
in headers as the cookie token you get from /sanctum/csrf-token is encrypted and it does not match session csrf token by itself, so it needs to decrypt via this method in CsrfVerify middleware

```
protected function getTokenFromRequest($request)
{
    $token = $request->input('_token') ?: $request->header('X-CSRF-TOKEN');

    if (! $token && $header = $request->header('X-XSRF-TOKEN')) {
        try {
            $token = CookieValuePrefix::remove($this->encrypter->decrypt($header, static::serialized()));
        } catch (DecryptException $e) {
            $token = '';
        }
    }

    return $token;
}
```

when putting either X-CSRF-TOKEN to header or _token to inputs, it does not decrypt and they would not match

#2 they did match anyway and I found out that the issue was, that my middleware was not first in api middlewares - if there is EncryptCookies::class before, it breaks the session csrf token value and they wont match

```
\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
```

took me more than 8 hours and finally with ChatGPT I debug this via logs in middlewares